# R plot: how to make a histogram with horizontal lines using plot()

Tags: r, graph, charts, plot, data-visualization

How can I use `plot` to turn this plot sideways so the histogram bars are horizontal?

```
size<- abs(rnorm(20,10,10))
age<-c(seq(1, 20, by=2))
plot(size~age, type=("n")); lines(size~age, type=c("l"), lines(size~age, type=c("h")))
```

[image]

What I want is roughly something like this, with the histogram lines horizontal:

[image]

which I did with

```
plot(size~age, type=("n"), yaxt="n", xaxt="n", ylab=""); lines(size~age, type=c("l"), lines(size~age, type=c("h"))); axis(4); axis(1,las=2)
```

and then rotating the image output in other software.

I'd like to know how I can use the `plot` function to get the output plot sideways so I can make groups of them in `R` without having to rotate them outside of `R`.

**UPDATE** Thanks to the very helpful suggestion from @csgillespie I've got this, which has got me on my way:

```
size<- abs(rnorm(20,10,10)) 
age<-c(seq(1, 40, by=2)) # sorry for the typo in the first set of example data above
plot(-age~size, type="n",yaxt="n", ylab="Age", xlab="Size")
lines(-age~size)
segments(0, -age, size, -age)
axis(2, labels=c(seq(0,max(age), by=5)), at=-c(seq(0,max(age), by=5)), las=1) # this is a more general approach to labelling the axis ticks
```

and here's resulting plot (not pretty yet, but I think I can do the rest from here):

[image]

Comment: Further comments you may find here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3792803/is-it-possible-to-rotate-a-plot-in-r-base-graphics

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get what you want by using `-age` then adding the scale manually.

```
plot(-age~size, type="n",yaxt="n", xlab="", ylab="Age")
lines(-age~size)
segments(0, -age, size, -age)
axis(2, labels=c(0,5,10,15,20), at=-c(0,5,10,15,20), las=1)
```

The code above produces an identical plot to you example figure, except, the y-axis label has been rotated. If you want the y-axis label to be rotated, then use `ylab=""` in the plot command and add it manually with `text`

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much! I wasn't aware it was a simple as changing the sign in the function. I also had not come across `segments` before, so that's very helpful. I went with a more general approach to labeling the tick marks (see my update) which is more efficient for my real data. Thanks again