# Rotate legend in base graphics

Tags: r, graphics, rotation, legend

I am wanting to rotate a legend to be placed outside the graph on the right axis. I can place the legend outside the graph, but I cannot figure out how to rotate it. I tried using `las=2`, but that clearly didn't work. Note: I am using all other axes, or I would place the legend above the graph with two columns to achieve the same look.

A general example of what I have already:

```
par(mar=c(6,4,5,4)+0.1)
plot(0,type="n")
legend(x="right",
       legend=c("Control Chemical","Test Chemcials"),
       bty="n",
       fill=c("Darkgreen","Dodgerblue4"),
       title="Legend Title",
       inset=c(-0.2,0),
       xpd=TRUE,
       horiz=TRUE)
```

The margins may need some adjustment, but I can easily make those once I figure out how to rotate the legend.

For additional clarification, what I am hoping to achieve is similar to:

```
legend(x="top",
       legend=c("Control Chemical","Test Chemcials"),
       bty="n",
       fill=c("Darkgreen","Dodgerblue4"),
       title="Legend Title",inset=c(0,-0.3),
       xpd=TRUE,
       horiz=TRUE)
```

But on the right axis rather than the top axis.

Comment: I don't think it's possible, and even gridBase won't help as it cannot use rotated viewports. Is there any reason not to use lattice/ggplot2/grid?

Comment: @baptiste The simplest answer is I haven't learned ggplot yet, because I have been able to do everything I need in base graphics or lattice. If it's not possible I can just make the right margin bigger than I'd like and place a normal legend outside the figure. I already have a lot of code drawing a pretty complex plot - hence why I cannot place the legend in the plotting region. For now it would not be worth work to learn how to implement all of the graph features in ggplot.

Comment: if you don't mind a somewhat ugly workaround, you _could potentially_ set up a layout with gridBase and in the right viewport plot [a rasterised version](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10097858/471093) of the legend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most sensible option I could think of is to set up two drawing regions with the help of gridBase, and use a grid-based function for the legend (because grobs can always be rotated). Lattice has one (simpleKey I think), but vcd probably has the [closest match](http://rss.acs.unt.edu/Rdoc/library/vcd/html/grid_legend.html) to the base version.

Note that if you don't need to resize the window, you probably can get away without using gridBase at all: just give enough margin on the right, and tweak the x and y coordinates to push the grid legend at the right location.

Here's a workable example,

```
library(vcd)
par(mar=c(6,4,5,4)+0.1)
plot(0,type="n")

g = grid_legend(0.5, 0.5, pch=c(22,22), col=c("red", "blue"),
                gp=gpar(fill = c("Darkgreen","Dodgerblue4")),
                labels=c("Control Chemical","Test Chemicals"), 
                title = "Legend Title", draw=FALSE)

grid.draw(grobTree(g, vp=viewport(x=0.93,angle=-90)))
```

[image]

Comment: I am not sure if this should be an additional question, but is there a way to mimic the `ncol=2` or `horiz=TRUE` calls to `graphics::legend` in `vdc::grid_legend`? And just a quick note: the fill portion of your code does not work like I think you intended.

Comment: grid_legend does seem to be fairly limited, looking at its code. The fill parameter is a bit useless here, indeed, and for this purpose one would be better off using a different square shape with only colour. If you want more flexibility, you'll probably have to write your own function.

Comment: I was afraid that would be the case. Thanks for the follow-up!

Comment: you could put a second legend with an offset y position, to mimic a second column (not title, and no box, probably)