# R: capture a raster matrix of a plot, grid::grid.cap function not working

Tags: r, graphics, grid, raster

I'm trying to reproduce some `grid` package examples, specifically those which involve the `grid.cap` function, to "capture" the current plot raster matrix. Examples [here](https://journal.r-project.org/archive/2011-1/RJournal_2011-1_Murrell.pdf) (Paul Murrell's article, Spanish flag example) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20677589/alternative-to-grid-cap-for-rotating-tilting-an-image-plot-in-r).

But `grid.cap` will simply not work for me as is, unless I open a new window with `dev.new()`/`dev.off()`:

```
# not working
plot(1:10)
cap <- grid::grid.cap()
is.null(cap)
[1] TRUE

# working
dev.new()
plot(1:10)
cap <- grid::grid.cap()
dev.off()
is.null(cap)
[1] FALSE
dim(cap)
[1] 672 672
```

I'm using a standard R 3.4.1 on Windows 7 (see `sessionInfo()`).

- Why is this happening?
- What can I do to fix this?
- If I can't fix this are there alternative ways to "capture" a plot's raster matrix without actually popping it up in a window or better yet without actually plotting it, e.g. capturing a `ggplot` object?

> ```
> > sessionInfo()
> R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30)
> Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
> Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1
>
> Matrix products: default
>
> locale:
> [1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
> [3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
> [5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    
>
> attached base packages:
> [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
>
> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
> [1] directlabels_2017.03.31 compiler_3.4.1          tools_3.4.1             yaml_2.1.14            
> [5] grid_3.4.1              quadprog_1.5-5
> ```