# Rotate plot in R

Tags: r, graph, plot, rotation

I would like to rotate my whole plot in R including axis, sub, titles etc. (So like rotate it 90 degrees to the left)
This is so when I put the graphs into a (landscape) document i can fit two (rotated) graphs on one page without distorting the image too much (making the page they are on a portrait page)

If this is not possible, then do you know how to rotate image files in Rmarkdown?

Here is a picture of the graphs on the same page

[image: original graphs]

Here is a picture of how i would like them to look

[image: required graphs]

Here is a random example graph to work with:

```
n<-c(54,65.5,52,587,55,23,545,222,45)
plot.ts(n,main="Example",sub="Random")
```

Comment: See [Is it possible to rotate a plot in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3792803/is-it-possible-to-rotate-a-plot-in-r-base-graphics)