# How to show the id of outliers on a boxplot

Tags: r, boxplot, outliers

How can you view the id of the outliers in a boxplot?

```r
structure(list(pot = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 8L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 29L, 30L, 
31L, 32L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 
20L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 
45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 69L, 
70L, 71L, 72L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 73L, 74L, 75L, 76L, 57L, 58L, 
59L, 60L, 77L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 81L, 82L, 83L, 84L, 101L, 102L, 
103L, 104L, 85L, 86L, 87L, 88L, 105L, 106L, 107L, 108L, 89L, 
90L, 91L, 92L, 109L, 110L, 111L, 112L, 93L, 94L, 95L, 96L, 113L, 
114L, 115L, 116L, 97L, 98L, 99L, 100L, 117L, 118L, 119L, 120L, 
121L, 122L, 123L, 124L, 141L, 142L, 143L, 144L, 125L, 126L, 127L, 
128L, 145L, 146L, 147L, 148L, 129L, 130L, 131L, 132L, 149L, 150L, 
151L, 152L, 133L, 134L, 135L, 136L, 153L, 154L, 155L, 156L, 137L, 
138L, 139L, 140L, 157L, 158L, 159L, 160L), rep = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), cultivar = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Dinninup", 
"Riverina", "Seaton Park", "Yarloop"), class = "factor"), Waterlogging = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Non-waterlogged", 
"Waterlogged"), class = "factor"), P = c(12.1, 12.1, 12.1, 12.1, 
12.1, 12.1, 12.1, 12.1, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 
15.17, 15.17, 18.24, 18.24, 18.24, 18.24, 18.24, 18.24, 18.24, 
18.24, 24.39, 24.39, 24.39, 24.39, 24.39, 24.39, 24.39, 24.39, 
48.35, 48.35, 48.35, 48.35, 48.35, 48.35, 48.35, 48.35, 12.1, 
12.1, 12.1, 12.1, 12.1, 12.1, 12.1, 12.1, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 
15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 18.24, 18.24, 18.24, 18.24, 
18.24, 18.24, 18.24, 18.24, 24.39, 24.39, 24.39, 24.39, 24.39, 
24.39, 24.39, 24.39, 48.35, 48.35, 48.35, 48.35, 48.35, 48.35, 
48.35, 48.35, 12.1, 12.1, 12.1, 12.1, 12.1, 12.1, 12.1, 12.1, 
15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 18.24, 
18.24, 18.24, 18.24, 18.24, 18.24, 18.24, 18.24, 24.39, 24.39, 
24.39, 24.39, 24.39, 24.39, 24.39, 24.39, 48.35, 48.35, 48.35, 
48.35, 48.35, 48.35, 48.35, 48.35, 12.1, 12.1, 12.1, 12.1, 12.1, 
12.1, 12.1, 12.1, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 
15.17, 18.24, 18.24, 18.24, 18.24, 18.24, 18.24, 18.24, 18.24, 
24.39, 24.39, 24.39, 24.39, 24.39, 24.39, 24.39, 24.39, 48.35, 
48.35, 48.35, 48.35, 48.35, 48.35, 48.35, 48.35), total = c(3.66, 
2.02, 1.59, 1.67, 2.12, 2.46, 1.79, 2.09, 2.03, 2.13, 1.83, 2.34, 
2.66, 2.2, 1.79, 1.97, 2.17, 2.44, 1.49, 2.19, 2.92, 2.43, 1.58, 
2.07, 2.48, 2.49, 1.69, 2.1, 2.38, 2.52, 2.41, 2.46, 2.22, 2.07, 
1.97, 2.3, 2.48, 3.16, 1.76, 2.38, 2.81, 2.64, 2.59, 3.28, 3.18, 
2.57, 2.9, 3, 2.38, 2.72, 2.58, 2.73, 3.06, 3.01, 3.01, 2.77, 
2.95, 2.36, 2.91, 2.38, 3.33, 3.19, 3.17, 3.16, 3.16, 3.2, 2.58, 
3.71, 3.11, 2.7, 2.92, 1.93, 2.95, 2.57, 2.68, 2.48, 3.34, 2.75, 
2.52, 1.88, 1.19, 0.57, 0.64, 0.66, 1.13, 1.28, 0.85, 0.96, 1.34, 
2.14, 0.63, 1.27, 1.13, 0.64, 1.21, 1.95, 1.11, 0.91, 0.75, 0.63, 
1.06, 1.07, 1.05, 0.8, 1.41, 1.13, 0.75, 0.89, 1.98, 1.27, 1.01, 
1, 1.16, 0.64, 0.64, 1.02, 1.03, 1.13, 0.79, 0.6, 3.88, 2.79, 
2.73, 2.77, 3.54, 2.05, 1.51, 1.88, 3.86, 3.13, 1.97, 3.46, 3.98, 
3.6, 2.12, 2.86, 2.95, 1.65, 1.94, 2.53, 2.21, 1.94, 2.05, 2.22, 
3, 3.28, 1.55, 3.85, 2.4, 2.1, 1.98, 1.81, 2.48, 1.66, 2.06, 
1.23, 3.75, 1.99, 1.67, 1.93)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-160L))
```

```r
boxplot(total~cultivar*as.factor(P),data=x)
```

[image: boxplot with outliers]

This is what I am after....

[image: desired result]

I have tried following example but does not work....

```
boxplot(total~cultivar*as.factor(P),data=x,id=list(n=Inf))
```

Identifying the outliers on the plot will make it easier to remove them from analysis. For some reason its not as straightforward as I thought. The post is asking me to add more details but I think there is sufficient.

Comment: What are these variables in the plot you want?  lfp? wc? k5?

Comment: the second plot is just showing us how the outliers are labelled. The first plot is the one im working with: boxplot(total~cultivar*as.factor(P),data=x)

Comment: So what Im trying to figure out is how to label the outliers like in the second plot

Comment: I get a different boxplot from the data that you provided.

Comment: @G5W first plot is what they get from their code, second one is the desired output.

Comment: Besides the answers below, further reading: https://www.r-statistics.com/2011/01/how-to-label-all-the-outliers-in-a-boxplot/

Comment: If I run OP's code on OP's data, I do not get OP's first plot.

Comment: @G5W same for me, though I dismissed that as a sampling issue. \*shrug\*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*You can use the `car` package:*

```
library(car)

Boxplot(total ~ cultivar*as.factor(P), id.method="y", data = x)
```

[image]

#### *Update:*

***Is it possible to flip the coordinates in `car::Boxplot`?***

For the sake of the challenge, I tried some hacky methods. After all, I was able to ***rotate*** the plot, but it's not as conventional as it is for `ggplot2::coord_flip`. Here, I am just rotating the plot. So, the labels are still in their previous alignment. We can go further, remove the labels and rewrite them, but that would defeat the whole purpose of this solution which is simplicity.

```r
library(car)
library(gridGraphics)

p <- Boxplot(total ~ cultivar*as.factor(P), id.method="y", data = x)

grab_grob <- function(){
  grid.echo()
  grid.grab()
}

g <- grab_grob()
grid.newpage()
pushViewport(viewport(width=0.5,angle=90))
grid.draw(g)
```

[image]

Comment: I love it when I have 30+ lines of code in an answer and somebody comes along with a one-liner.

Comment: @r2evans sorry, didn't mean to downplay your efforts ;)

Comment: How do you flip this graph so you can easily read the labels like the answer below?

Comment: I think you can add  `horizontal = TRUE`, since I think it uses the base R `boxplot` internally (which takes that argument).

Comment: Unfortunately, horizontal = TRUE does not work with "Boxplot" from the car package.

Comment: @EliottReed I am afraid it's not possible for `car::Boxplot` to be rotated. If you load `gridGraphics` and save the boxplot into a variable, e.g. `p`, and then run `str(p)` it will return the outliers plus some warnings that says the plot cannot be clipped for rotations, etc. This answer explains a bit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3793658/6461462 It is something that package carer should add to the functions: https://github.com/cran/car. Issue of readability can be taken care of by defining a better size or splitting the plot into chunks (some ideas out of thin air). Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, though `boxplot` does return a `list` structure that provides the *values* of the outliers (e.g., `boxplot(..., plot=FALSE)$out`), this doesn't help here since there are equal values in other groups that are not outliers there. (In fact, I find using `$out` always a bit risky unless it is just one group.)

But you can use `$stats` to get the whisker parameters and find everything yourself. Unfortunately, this is not a one-liner.

First, though, since I don't know what you mean by "id", I'll add something to the data:

```r
x$id <- seq_len(nrow(x))
```

## `base` R

```r
bp <- boxplot(total ~ cultivar * as.factor(P), data = x)
lims <- data.frame(nm = bp$names, t(bp$stats[c(1,5),]))
tmpx <- merge(transform(x, nm = paste(cultivar, as.factor(P), sep = ".")), lims, by = "nm", all.x = TRUE)
tmpx <- subset(tmpx, total < X1 | total > X2)
tmpx$xval <- match(tmpx$nm, bp$names)
text(total ~ xval, id, data = tmpx, adj = c(-0.5, 0.5))
```

[image: base R boxplot, with outlier ids]

Overlaying text over boxplots might be a problem for you; you can play with various shifting and/or flipping the coordinates to control this. Clipping (not shown here, but when a text label disappears out of the plot region) can also be a problem, so you might need to manually control the limits of the plot region.

## `dplyr`

In case you like the `tidyverse`-way of looking at data-munging, here's an alternative that produces the same plot.

```r
library(dplyr)
bp <- boxplot(total ~ cultivar * as.factor(P), data = x)
x %>%
  mutate( nm = paste(cultivar, as.factor(P), sep = ".") ) %>%
  left_join(data.frame(nm = bp$names, t(bp$stats[c(1,5),]), stringsAsFactors = FALSE),
            by = "nm") %>%
  filter(total < X1 | total > X2) %>%
  mutate(xval = match(nm, bp$names)) %>%
  text(data = ., total ~ xval, as.character(id), adj = c(-0.5, 0.5))
```

(Same plot.)

## `dplyr` and `ggplot2`

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
bp <- boxplot(total ~ cultivar * as.factor(P), data = x, plot = FALSE)
x %>%
  mutate( nm = paste(cultivar, as.factor(P), sep = ".") ) %>%
  left_join(data.frame(nm = bp$names, t(bp$stats[c(1,5),]), stringsAsFactors = FALSE),
            by = "nm") %>%
  mutate(outlier = total < X1 | total > X2) %>%
  ggplot(aes(interaction(cultivar, P), total)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  geom_text(aes(label = id), hjust = -0.5, data = ~ filter(., outlier)) +
  coord_flip()
```

[image: ggplot2 boxplot, with outlier ids]

I chose to flip the coordinates so that the labels would be all included and shown, but it's not required for the method. One trick I used is that the `data=` argument to the `ggplot2` functions can take an expression (I think of it as a tilde-function), which allows subsetting of the main dataset in-place. Here I use `dplyr::filter`, but in this case it is just as easy to use `subset` (`base` R) in case you are not otherwise using `dplyr`.