# How to rotate the plot in r base package graphics?

Tags: r, dendrogram

I know this is a little bit too much, but I am plotting a dendrogram plot in r, and here is my code:

```
dd <- dist(scale(full[,c(1,2,3,4)]),method="euclidean")
hc = hclust(dd,method="ward.D2")
dend <- color_branches(as.dendrogram(hc),6)

labels_colors(dend) <-
  rainbow_hcl(6)[sort_levels_values(
    as.numeric(classified[, 9])[order.dendrogram(dend)]
  )]
plot(dend,horiz=T)
```

and I got this plot:
[image]
Is there any way can do mirror symmetry to make it like this:(please ignore the difference in colour)
[image]

Comment: Which libraries are you using?  For example, the `full` function in line 1 isn't from `base`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3792803/is-it-possible-to-rotate-a-plot-in-r-base-graphics#32198964 shows a way to rotate base r plots ... doesn't do to bad in your example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```r
plot_horiz.dendrogram(dend, side = TRUE)
```

should do the trick. See https://rdrr.io/cran/dendextend/f/vignettes/FAQ.Rmd

Comment: exactly what I'm looking for, appreciate it！