# dev.off() skips a device on the device stack

Tags: r

I always thought that the devices in R work like a stack; so that if you have more of them open, and you close a device with `dev.off()`, it just pops the current device off the stack and you continue drawing on the last device.

But this example shows otherwise!

I opened a cascade of devices

```
plot(1:1) 

png(filename = "trial.png", width = 7, height = 7, units = "in", res = 600)

dev.new() # I need another auxilliary Windows device, for operations like 
          # 45 degree rotation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32198964/684229

dev.list()
# windows     png windows 
#      2       3       4
```

Now I will close the last device (windows 4). I need the "png 3" device to become current. But `dev.off()` skips it and makes "windows 2" current! :

```
dev.off()
# windows 
#       2
```

Now, e.g. `points(1.1, 1.1)` will draw to the windows device, not to the png device.

Questions:

1. How is this possible? Is this some kind of feature, or a bug?
2. How can I make `dev.off()` work like a stack? I need to.

Comment: The documentation for `dev.off` says "If the current device is shut down and any other devices are open, the NEXT open device is made current". You therefore need to use `dev.prev()` after closing, to go back to the end of the (circular) list.

Comment: @AndrewGustar What is meant by "NEXT open"? I thought that should be the one at the top of the stack, i.e. "png 3".

Comment: The list of devices is circular, i.e the next one after the last is the first one. So if you've just opened windows 4, and closed it, the next one will be 2, not 3.

Comment: I for one look at the use of `dev.new()` as adding to a _stack_ (from a data-structure perspective) and not a circular list or queue. I find the logic of "next" going to "first" instead of "most-recent" to be counter-intuitive, regardless of what documentation may warn about it. I can't think of situations where the current logic would make more sense than (say) requiring one to explicitly set the active device when the active device is closed.

Comment: @AndrewGustar ok, thanks... but what is the logic behind that circular list? I kind of miss the point, similarly as r2evans wrote.

Comment: Tomas, is your need to treat it like a stack contingent on using `grDevices::dev.off`, or would you feel okay using a custom function? Are you trying to make it easier for users of a package where compliance with base R is required? Lacking that, I might use something as naive as `devoff2 <- function() { dev.off(); if (L <- length(dev.list())) dev.set(L); }`