# grid.newpage() conflicts with plot.new()

Tags: r, r-grid

I am following [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32198964/684229) to make a base graphics plot rotated 45 degrees. Now I came to a situation when I need to call `grid.newpage()` to basically clear the grid's viewport tree, but I also need to call `plot.new()` so that I can plot the plot title. But if I call both, I will get an extra blank page on the pdf device:

```
pdf(file = "trialD1.pdf", width = 7, height = 7) 

{ # this code belongs to my custom function, which should work for any device
dev <- dev.cur()
dev.new() # auxilliary device

plot(1,1)

library(gridGraphics) # solution to rotate 45 deg - https://stackoverflow.com/a/32198964/684229
grid.echo() # redraws it without reason, no matter what I try (invisible(), x = NULL, newpage = FALSE)
g <- grid.grab() # again redraws it without reason... even with invisible() 
dev.off() # closes auxilliary device

dev.set(dev) # need to come back to the device that was active before, because dev.off() could skip it (https://stackoverflow.com/q/77426629/684229)
grid.newpage()
plot.new() # so that title() can work 
pushViewport(viewport(width = 0.7072, height = 0.7072, angle=45))
grid.draw(g)
title(main = "Hello world", cex.main = 2)
} # end of function

dev.off() # pdf
```

I just wanted to get one page pdf with the plot displayed on the second page, which looks like this:

[image]

**WARNING:** If I remove `grid.newpage()`, it looks like it works, but for pdf only; if we e.g. use it for Windows plotting device multiple times, it will start to behave erroneously since the viewports keep stacking as the viewport tree didn't get cleared with `grid.newpage()`. So, looks like `grid.newpage()` is kind of a "reset" function for the grid stuff that needs to be called when new image is drawn. Or, one needs some replacement for it...

Comment: once you have converted the plot to a rob, why not plot the title using a `grid` function e.g. `grid.text`

Comment: ps as far as i can see, gid.echo doesn't redraw it for me

Comment: @user20650 1) Thanks for the tip on the `grid.text()`. The `title()` is nicer since it places it automatically at the place of graph title. 2) I can observe this redrawing when plotting on the Windows device in basic Rgui.

Comment: weird on the redrawing .. while  I cant see it on ubuntu it does seem to open a new blank window

Comment: `grid.newpage` and `plot.new` are actually assuming different devices. The grid/lattice system is a later addition to R than the default plotting device. It takes extra effort to make them somewhat compatible. See pkg:gridBase